# Conditionally extend template with Odoo QWeb

Tags: odoo

I added a boolean field to my `stock.picking.type` model called `x_is_dropship_aggregate_picking_type`. This field is `False` for all picking types in my database except for one.

I am trying to make some changes to the Kanban card for the picking type that has `x_is_dropship_aggregate_picking_type == true`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my template created through the Odoo V10 UI. It inherits from the `stock.picking.type.kanban` view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='count_picking_backorders']" position="after">
        <field name="x_is_dropship_aggregate_picking_type"/>
    </xpath>        
    <templates>
        <t t-extend="kanban-box">
            <t t-if="record.x_is_dropship_aggregate_picking_type.raw_value" t-jquery="button" t-operation="replace">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span>100 To Receive</span>
                </button>
            </t>
        </t>
    </templates>
</data>
```

As you can see on this line:

```
<t t-if="record.x_is_dropship_aggregate_picking_type.raw_value" t-jquery="button" t-operation="replace">
```

I am attempting to only alter the parent template if the value of this field is `true`. Unfortunately, every Kanban card within the view is getting changed, not just the one I want. It seems that `t-if` and `t-jquery` do not working together in that way.

Is there any way to conditionally alter this view and leave it unchanged otherwise?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution for this?